# Why can't I remove language variants like English (NZ), etc.?

Tags: language-support, locale

I'd like to remove some unwanted languages from my system.
I only use Italian, and English UK and US.
In "Systems Settings" I can find a lot of languages that I don't even know why they have been installed. However, although I am an administrator, I can't remove the unwanted languages (as you can see the "-" is greyed out).
I have tried running "sudo gnome-control-center" but there the only language displayed is English.
Thanks a lot in advance for the help!
Luca

[image: t]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Languages with localized variants are provided in a package:
- English contains AU, US, UK, NZ, SA, etc. variants
- Chinese contains variants, etc.

You can't remove specific variants without removing the whole package (from the desktop).

If you are adventurous, you can try removing those locales via the command-line, e.g. `en_NZ.UTF_8`, etc.

Comment: ..but why should I have them? I think they just bloat my spell checkers list and so on...